# Can I use Umbraco Macros this way

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

So I have been looking on how to do this, but no luck.

I want to create Macros which I can add controllers, and custom models and include them on a PageType.

My Model:

```
public class PersonalDetail : RenderModel
{
    public PersonalDetail(IPublishedContent content) : base(content)
    {
    }

    public PersonalDetail(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base(content, culture)
    {
    }

    public decimal Pk { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string contactNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string cellNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }

    public string IDNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public char gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int maritalStatusPk { get; set; }

    public int weight { get; set; }

    public double height { get; set; }
}
```

My View: (Only has the one line in)

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Models.PersonalDetail>
```

My Controller: (This never even gets hit)

```
public class TestController : RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Test(RenderModel model)
    {
        var personDetail = new Models.PersonalDetail(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Error is :

```
Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.PartialViewMacroModel to model type Models.PersonalDetail
```

Any help or ideas at this point will help

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your question with a sample of the source code for the Macro Partial view?

Instead of `RenderMvcController`, you may want to consider using a `SurfaceController`.  The difference is that the former is generally used for overriding the default functionality (known as *Hijacking Umbraco Routes*) for rendering a Content Node; while the latter is used more as the basis for Partial Views etc. that are included in other Views.

See [Surface Controllers](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/surface-controllers) in the documentation for more details, also the [Controllers](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Implementation/Controllers/) overview gives a good rundown on the various Controllers available within Umbraco and how to use them.

For using `RenderMvcController`, see [this documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-controllers)

Aside from that, your Test method doesn't seem to be using `personDetail` variable as the model at all.

Comment: Hi, So yes I want to create partial view, the one line @inherits UmbracoViewPage<Models.PersonalDetail> is only thing in the partial view, which is then used in the Macro. I know my Test method does not use the model, I was trying to change and test with other things and what's more, it does not "hit" that method at all. Hence my confusion

Comment: Don’t use RenderMVCController for macros - it’s not designed for that.  Use a SurfaceController with a Partial View and include that in the macro instead